# Fancybox resize on load not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using fancybox 2.1.5, and I'm trying to resize the modal housing the images before having them popup. It doesn't seem to be working as expected, the images don't seem to resize. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( '#content' ).find( 'img' ).each(function() {
        jQuery(this).parent( 'a' ).fancybox({   
            type: 'image',
            autoSize : false,
                beforeLoad : function() {         
                    this.width  = 300;  
                    this.height = 150;
                }
        });
    });
});
```

Working Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1a02ehua/1/

Answer (score 0):

I was using an older, deprecated function beforeLoad which works with versions prior to Fancybox 2.1.5. After some adjustment the new, working, function is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( '#content' ).find( 'img' ).each(function() {
        jQuery(this).parent( 'a' ).fancybox({   
            beforeShow : function() {         
                this.width  = 500;  
                this.height = 300;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Note the 'beforeShow' change**

Thanks.

Comment: For the record: `beforeLoad` is **not** a deprecated callback and still a valid API option for v2.1.5 [See documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) ("callbacks" tab) `beforeLoad` and `beforeShow` are intended for different events: `this.width` won't work inside `beforeLoad` because you are trying to set a property to an element that hasn't been loaded.